# Mail Server API for creating email accounts using JavaMail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I would like to create a new POP3/imap email account programmatically when a user registers for my site.

Is there any solution for my problem.because in some sites its mentioned, implementaion with java mail is difficult.

Any body can help on this.

Comment: The JavaMail API does **not** provide this feature. You'll have to check how it is done programatically with your mail server and implement that in Java.